# Clearing/Emptying a lineChart in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, dataprovider, series, linechart

I have a line chart in flex with a dateTime axis. I am setting the dataprovider to that linechart via actionscript. The graph gets drawn. The problem occurs when i assign a null to the dataprovider so that the graph becomes empty.

Actual code looks similar to the code below :

```
var actualValues:XMLList=flowChartDP.upFlows;
var localSeries1:LineSeries = new LineSeries();
localSeries1.dataProvider = actualValues;
localSeries1.yField = "flow";
localSeries1.xField = "time";
localSeries1.setStyle("form","curve");
var currentSeries1:Array =lineChart.series;
currentSeries1.push(localSeries1);
lineChart.series = currentSeries1;
var actualValues2:XMLList=flowChartDP.downFlows;
var localSeries2:LineSeries = new LineSeries();
localSeries2.dataProvider = actualValues2;
localSeries2.yField = "flow";
localSeries2.xField = "time";
localSeries2.setStyle("form","curve");
var currentSeries2:Array =lineChart.series;
currentSeries2.push(localSeries2);
lineChart.series = currentSeries2;
```

And I will be adding two more series exactly in the samefashion to the lineChart.Although i guess not the best way of writung the code this one works fine.
The problem is with resetting the graph.

I have a button which when clicked does:
    lineChart.dataprovider=null;
    lineChart.series=null;

But my flash player(FP 10 debugger version) throws up the following error

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at mx.charts::AxisRenderer/measureHorizontalGutters()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\datavisualization\src\mx\charts\AxisRenderer.as:2275]
    at mx.charts::AxisRenderer/calcRotationAndSpacing()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\datavisualization\src\mx\charts\AxisRenderer.as:1889]
    at mx.charts::AxisRenderer/adjustGutters()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\datavisualization\src\mx\charts\AxisRenderer.as:1565]
    at mx.charts.chartClasses::CartesianChart/updateAxisLayout()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\datavisualization\src\mx\charts\chartClasses\CartesianChart.as:2133]
    at mx.charts.chartClasses::CartesianChart/updateDisplayList()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\datavisualization\src\mx\charts\chartClasses\CartesianChart.as:1391]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateDisplayList()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8531]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateDisplayList()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:663]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:736]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1072]
```

What is the solution? It doesn't throw the error when

```
lineChart.series=null;
```

is removed. But the statement

```
lineChart.dataprovider=null;
```

doesnt make the chart empty either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a simple application I created to re-create your issue. Setting the dataProvider to null does clear the chart without any exceptions for me. Run it and see. I say your problem is somewhere else.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application
   xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"             
   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" >

    <fx:Script><![CDATA[

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        [Bindable]
        public var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {Month:"Jan", Profit:2000, Expenses:1500, Amount:450},
            {Month:"Feb", Profit:1000, Expenses:200, Amount:600},
            {Month:"Mar", Profit:1500, Expenses:500, Amount:300}
        ]);


        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            myChart.dataProvider = null;

        }

    ]]></fx:Script>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout />
    </s:layout>


    <mx:Panel title="Line Chart">
        <mx:LineChart id="myChart" 
                      dataProvider="{expenses}" 
                      showDataTips="true"
                      >
            <mx:horizontalAxis>
                <mx:CategoryAxis 
                    dataProvider="{expenses}" 
                    categoryField="Month"
                    />
            </mx:horizontalAxis>
            <mx:series>
                <mx:LineSeries 
                    yField="Profit" 
                    displayName="Profit"
                    />
                <mx:LineSeries 
                    yField="Expenses" 
                    displayName="Expenses"
                    />
            </mx:series>
        </mx:LineChart>
        <mx:Legend dataProvider="{myChart}"/>
    </mx:Panel>

    <s:Button click="button1_clickHandler(event)" label="Clear" />

</s:Application>
```

Comment: I am creating series on the flow dyanamically and assigning dataproviders to the series also.

Comment: Whether it's dynamically created or set at run time, unless there is a bug in Flex, which is rare, both should work just as the same. All this code is anyway converted to ActionScript when compiled. Can you update your question with the relevant code? Show the code for the button.

Comment: The dataproviders are XMLList 

Objects.For example  var actualValues:XMLList=flowChartDP.flows; var 

localSeries1:LineSeries = new LineSeries(); 

localSeries1.dataProvider = actualValues;  localSeries1.yField = 

"flow";  localSeries1.xField = "time"; 

localSeries1.setStyle("form","curve");  var currentSeries1:Array = 

lineChart.series;  currentSeries1.push(localSeries1);  

lineChart.series = currentSeries1;

Comment: And I will be adding three more 

series exactly in the samefashion to the lineChart.

The linechart code is       <mx:LineChart width="100%" height="94%" 

id="lineChart" dataProvider="{flowChartDP}"  showDataTips="true"  
fontSize="12" color="#000000">

Comment: I have updated the question Ranhiru. Thanks for looking into it. I was also checking this with an example like yours and it works fine. So i am looking into my code now. Hope the updated question will clarify the problem some more..